# How should I make a long PHP request via AJAX, periodically check for status updates, and close the script if the request cancels?

Tags: php, ajax, http, session-variables, session-cookies

Part of the PHP web app I'm developing needs to do the following:

1. Make an AJAX request to a PHP script, which could potentially take from one second to one hour, and display the output on the page when finished.
2. Periodically update a loading bar on the web page, defined by a status variable in the long running PHP script.
3. Allow the long running PHP script to detect if the AJAX request is cancelled, so it can shut down properly and in a timely fashion.

#### My current solution:

- **client.php:** Creates an AJAX request to request.php, followed by one request per second to status.php until the initial request is complete. Generates and passes along a unique identifier (uid) in case multiple instances of the app are running.
- **request.php:** Each time progress is made, saves the current progress percentage to $_SESSION["progressBar"][uid]. (It must run session_start() and session_write_close() each time.) When finished, returns the data that client.php needs.
- **status.php:** Runs session_start(), returns $_SESSION["progressBar"][uid], and runs session_write_close().

#### Where it falls short:

My solution fulfills my first two requirements. For the third, I would like to use connection_aborted() in **request.php** to know if the request is cancelled. BUT, the docs say:

> PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client. Simply using an echo statement does not guarantee that information is sent, see flush().

I could simply give meaningless output, but PHP *must* send a cookie every time I call session_start(). I want to use the same session, BUT the docs say:

> When using session cookies, specifying an id for session_id() will always send a new cookie when session_start() is called, regardless of if the current session id is identical to the one being set.

#### My ideas for solutions, none of which I'm happy with:

- A status database, or writing to temp files, or a task management system. This just seems more complicated than what I need!
- A custom session handler. This is basically the same as the above solution.
- Stream both progress data and result data in one request. This solves everything, but I would essentially be re-implementing AJAX. That can't be right.

Please tell me I'm missing something! Why doesn't PHP know immediately when a connection terminates? Why must PHP resend the cookie, even when it is exactly the same? An answer to any of these questions will be a big help!

My sincere thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set a second session variable, consisting of the unique request identifier and an access timestamp, from `status.php`.

If the client is closed it stops getting updates from `status.php` and the session variable stops being updated, which triggers a clean close in `request.php` if the variable isn't updated in a certain amount of time.

Comment: Good idea. While I'd still like to know if I can do this based on the primary request, (or why it's impossible) I think it's probably safe to assume that after 30 seconds of inactivity the client is gone for good.

Comment: I may be wrong about this, but it could have to do with minimising chatter between php and the client. In order to know that the client is no longer there, it has to attempt to send something to the client. It can't rely on headers because these would only work until output starts.

Comment: **But** on the TCP level, shouldn't the web server know when a connection is terminated? This level isn't my area, but I thought this was part of TCP.

Comment: TCP isn't a persistent connection, just a series of requests and replies. If you need a persistent connection you need to look into sockets or websockets.

Comment: That would explain it. Thanks.